# How can I disable the "Text format" pull-down for users that are creating or editing content?

Tags: nodes

Since the "Plain Text" format can't be deleted (within /admin/config/content/formats) the Text format pull-down will always contain it plus the default format that you would like for the user to use (i.e. Full HTML) when creating content.

When the user creates content (i.e. /node/add/article) I would like the "Text format" pull-down to be disabled so that they can't change it for non-administrators.

How can I disable the "Text format" pull-down for users that are creating or editing content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting rid of the text format pull-down by using hook_form_alter:

function workbench_moderation_custom_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if (isset($form['type']['#value']) && $form['type']['#value'] . '_node_form' == $form_id) {
    drupal_add_js('jQuery().ready(function(){jQuery(".filter-wrapper").hide();});', 'inline');
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

The absolute easiest way would be to hide the selection using CSS.

I only say this because there's nothing "bad" that can happen if someone does use the plain text format.

Otherwise you're looking at assigning custom permissions and probably using hook_form_alter()  which just seems like it's more trouble than it's worth!

```
.filter-wrapper { display: none; }
```

Comment: My co-worker tried the following and we are looking for best way to hide the "Text format" pull-down and this is her comment: "I added the style to global.css which is the main css for atf theme but it doesn't work.
In order to complete the request I have to add it in style.css in seven theme which is main theme for administration but this is core part of Drupal so I am not sure if it is okay."